# how to login with registered phone number and password in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-custom-user

here is the code for registration with email and password but how to do with phone number i have

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an username")

        user  = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username=username,
            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user  = self.create_user(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                password=password,
                username=username,
            )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username                = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login              = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # first_name                = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', ]

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

whenever i was trying to createsuper the it gives me the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.p
y", line 86, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3
\base.py", line 396, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: account_account

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__i
nit__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__i
nit__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\bas
e.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\manage
ment\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\bas
e.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\manage
ment\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 113, in handle
    error_msg = self._validate_username(username, verbose_field_name, database)
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\manage
ment\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 234, in _validate_username
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).get_by_natural_key(usernam
e)
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_u
ser.py", line 44, in get_by_natural_key
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.p
y", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py"
, line 411, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py"
, line 258, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py"
, line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py"
, line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=sel
f.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compi
ler.py", line 1152, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.p
y", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.p
y", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._exec
ute)
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.p
y", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.p
y", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line
90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.p
y", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\TIKAMS~1\DJANGO~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3
\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: account_account
```

please give me the suggestions if you can it will be great help

Comment: Missing migrations?

Comment: but i have migrated . when i was creating superuser then it was showing the error

Comment: Looks like you have inherited the abstract option from the `AbstractBaseUser`. Try with `class Meta: abstract = False` and a new migration.

Answer (score 0):

add field for the phone number and add the phone no in required fields

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone_number']
```